# 403 Forbidden ubuntu server

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2

Hello I have a problem with accessing my laravel website when I go into the website I get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.webuilder.co.uk Port 80
```

My error log is saying:

```
Permission denied: [client (my ip)] access to / denied (filesystem path '/var/fyproject/public') because search permissions are missing on component of the path
```

So what is going on?

Comment: unless you configured it that way, `/var/fyproject/public` seems wrong, it's usually `/var/www/` so the correct path will be `/var/www/fyproject/public`

Comment: where can I change this? what file?

Comment: `Search permissions are missing on component of the path`: one or more directories of `/var`, `/var/fyproject` or `/var/fyproject/public` do not have `execute`permission for the user running the httpd. `ls -ld`on those directories should read something like `rwx-rx-rx`.

Comment: It should be on your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf` or in another file in that same folder if you created a custom one.